# Adding fractions by n denominator in for_loop (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm trying to make it so it loops fractions as 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, etc up to 1/100, then add all them together and only show the sum and not the chain of fractions.

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
<?

$sum = 0;

for($n = 1;   $n<=1/100;  $n+=1/$n)
{
    $sum = $sum + $n;
}
echo $sum;
```

But it never gives me the right answer, which is 5.18. Any advice?

Comment: What does it give you?

Comment: The answer is 0. That's what it gives me.

Comment: `1/100` is less than `1`. That's why your loop doesn't run.

Answer (score 3):

You need to limit the loop. And you need to increment `$n`

```
$sum = 0;

for($n = 1;   $n<=100;   $n++)
{
    $sum = $sum + (1/$n);
}
echo $sum;

//answer 5.1873775176396
```

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, for a simple operation like this, your for loop does not even need a body.

```
$sum = 0;
for($n=1; $n<=100; $sum +=(1/$n++));
echo $sum;
```

See example four in the php [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) documentation.

Comment: true, you don't need a body and the code works but it's not PSR-2 compliant http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Answer (score 0):

```
for($n = 1;   $n<=;   $n+=1/$n)
```

You must define a limit insecond parameter of for, it runs in infinity

EDIT:

Between second and third parameter, you must insert `;`

Comment: I accidentally mis-typed the original post, $n<=; was supposed to be $n<=1/100, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sum = 0;

for ($n=1; $n<=100; $n++) {
    $sum = $sum + (1/$n);
}

echo $sum;

// or use round if you want it rounded
//echo round($sum,2);
```

This code is [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) compliant

Comment: Make it without `round()` and it is as OP asked.

Comment: I added round() because he expected 5.18 (which is wrong) it's 5.19

Comment: Ha, you ain't happening to be a mathematician?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
for ($n = 0, $sum = 0; $n < 100; $n++, $sum += 1 / $n);
echo $sum;
```